# How to write on-chain program leveraging the "Address Lookup Table" feature

Tags: account, program, on-chain

I would like to write an on-chain program that leverages the "Address Lookup Table" feature (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/26391). I would like the on-chain program to de-serialize the accounts loaded from the lookup table so the data stored inside can be used.

Specifically, given the following entrypoint def of a solana on-chain program:

```
pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey, // Public key of the account the hello world program was loaded into
    accounts: &[AccountInfo], // The account to say hello to
    _instruction_data: &[u8], // Ignored, all helloworld instructions are hellos
) -> ProgramResult {
    // Do something
}
```

Will the accounts from the lookup table be provided to my program via `accounts: &[AccountInfo]` argument? If yes, how will they be arranged? If no, do you have any further recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Address Lookup Tables are handled entirely by the runtime before anything gets to the program.  All you get in the processor is a longer `accounts` array.  There is nothing to change on program side.

There *are* however client side changes required to construct v0 transactions that can leverage ALTs.  SDK support is unavailable at present, but being worked on by the core team (sorry I have no ETA)